# Which non-stick pan to buy?

Tags: frying, pan, frying-pan

Recently, I found a small but deep scratch on my pan. I can see the metalic color on the scratch. I am not sure how much serious it is.

Now, I want to buy a new one. I see different prices with different qualities and I have no idea what to buy. I live alone and I cook for one person but sometimes for several meals (3 meals).

Some people suggest me to buy a thin one not thick one. Expect for thickness what is the difference between pans?

If I look at the pan's surface pattern, does it give me any clue?

I also see some pans with white dots on it. What are these types of pans?

[image]

Comment: The white speckled pans tend to be enameled steel.  I think there used to be multiple companies that made them, but the most common ones in the US are sold under the brand name 'GraniteWare'

Comment: Related: 
Are Non-Stick Bread Pans Destined to Fail?
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21858/are-non-stick-bread-pans-destined-to-fail  Throwing money at the problem does not seem to be an effective strategy here.

Comment: What kind of "pan" do you mean? The two objects in your image are baking dishes or cake pans and are designed for oven use only. To me, if someone said "non-stick pan" I would assume a stove top pan for cooking.

Comment: @Catija, great point. I mean pan. Not baking. For the photo, I appologize. It was misleading. but I could not find a better photo at that time. Now I fixed that.